# Why do I see voltage offset in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, current-transformer, offset

I am trying to measure AC voltage with the help of a 2mA/2mA current transformer with the following circuit. It seems to work fine.
[image: Current transformer out to OpAmp]

However, we can see that the secondary of the transformer is not closed when the op-amp is not energized. If the AC voltage is applied to the primary with the secondary open, a high voltage may appear at the secondary that may damage both CT and other electronics. To avoid this, I placed a small resistance in parallel to the transformer's secondary as shown below.

[image: Transformer secondary with a shunt resistance]

When I connect this, I see a offset in the Vo. I don't see a reason for the offset. This offset is also observed when the primary is not energized.

I am using LM358 with dual power supply of plus and minus 12V. The offset I am observing is 300mV

Comment: Why did you remove the ground from the transformer secondary?

Comment: @Hearth, It was a mistake. I have ground. I updated the image.

Comment: Which opamp and what is the value of the offset?

Comment: I am using LM358 with dual power supply of plus and minus 12v. The offset I am observing is 300mV

Comment: opamp input offset currents. You are supposed to have a burden resistor for CTs though so that is good you added one.

Comment: Note you may be able to reduce or eliminate that offset with a slight adjustable resistance to a power rail. But the proper solution is to pick a better op-amp with lower offset voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added 6.7 Ω across the input and, making an estimated guess your CT output resistance might have been several hundred ohms so, in effect, you have raised the noise and offset gain of the op-amp probably a hundred times.

If the input offset voltage of the op-amp is (say) 1 mV and the CT output winding resistance is (say) 670 Ω then the offset would be multiplied by 1 + 220/670 and you might have therefore seen about 1.33 mV on the output (not much).

However, your new noise and offset gain is going to be 1 + 220/6.7 = 34 and the offset will be seen as 34 mV at the output.

> *The offset I am observing is 300mV*

Well, the [LM358](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) (page 7) has a maximum input offset voltage of 7 mV so, my estimation of 34 mV at the output (based on an input offset of 1 mV) needs to be seven times higher at 238 mV. Is this close-enough to convince you?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you have explained. However, I have a quick input, the offset I measured is at the output terminal. Is there a chance that the 34mV offset at the input is amplified into 300mV offset at the output terminal?

Comment: I've amended my answer based on the fact that you are using an LM358. Yes, input offset multiplied by gain = output offset.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a large DC offset at the output because your DC gain is extremely high which will multiply the DC offset voltage at the opamp inputs. Place a DC blocking capacitor to lower the DC gain to unity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffPlLf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @qrk I cannot use a capacitor. At least, not the way shown in the circuit. I need to add a parallel resistance (burden resistance) across the secondary.

Comment: @SKGadi I modified the schematic to show the resistor across the secondary of the transformer. Would this work? The capacitor value needs to be chosen for the lowest frequency expected.

Comment: looks nice. I see one disadvantage in this circuit is: It will be a voltage amplifier rather than a transimpedance amplifier. I believe transimpedance amplifier is better when our goal is measuring current. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @SKGadi  At AC, the impedance of the capacitor, if chosen properly, will be very low which makes this a current input amplifier. You'll probably find that the capacitor values needs to be pretty large, perhaps around 1000uF. I suggest you use a SPICE simulator so you can see this for yourself.